# Have/get somebody (to) do sth

Tags: british-english, passive-voice

I was wondering if I may use this construction in a negative way.
Lemme explain it:

I have my mum not bring me the menu ( more or less it should be lile I don't have the menu brought, assuming it's correct)

I get my mum not to bring me the menu.

May I use this kinda construction?

Comment: You might note that eye-dialect forms like *lemme* and *kinda* are typically used to characterize the user's speech as slovenly or uneducated. I advise avoiding these forms except when your intent is clearly ironic.

Comment: There are 3.5 million Google hits for "get him not to" alone. "I'll have him not sing in the show' is probably acceptable, but sounds rarefied. Note that these both imply a default that is being negated (it doesn't make sense to say "I'll get him not to smoke in the house" if he doesn't at the moment).

Comment: I tell my mom not to bring me a menu.